# Eclipse gives: "An API baseline has not been set for the current work space." error

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna. After updating my sandbox, I started getting the following error message in multiple modules. Should I add an API baseline or just have the Eclipse ignore it?

Comment: That is really up to you. Read up about API baselines [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-api-tools/) and decide if they are useful for you.

Comment: Looks like I do not need them after all. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Unfortunately, the link has rotted. :-( [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511619/884502) may provide some of the information you're after. Hopefully it won't rot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My issue was resolved. Turns out I did not need the API baseline after all. For the ones who might be curious how to disable this error message (Eclipse Luna):

**Windows** -> **Preferences** -> **Plug-in Development** -> **API Baselines**

Under **Options** find **Missing API baseline** -> If **Error** is selected change it to **Warning** or **Ignore** -> **Apply**.

For further details check the [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-api-tools/) posted on [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449)`s comment.