# How to remove error "An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace" in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm cleaning up some eclipse projects and some of them keep reporting following error:

```
An API baseline has not been set for the current workspace
```

I don't want to use API baseline and I don't want to disable the reporting of this error in  Eclipse preferences as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473967/eclipse-gives-an-api-baseline-has-not-been-set-for-the-current-work-space-er).

How can I configure the project so that it does not use an API baseline and does not report this error? I tried removing ALL builders from my project, except the plain java builder and it still keeps reporting this error.